# Building a symmetric binary matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a matrix that is for example like this:

```
rownames    V1
a   1
c   3
b   2
d   4
y   2
q   4
i   1
j   1
r   3
```

I want to make a Symmetric binary matrix that it's dimnames of that is the same as rownames of above matrix. I want to fill these matrix by 1 & 0 in such a way that 1 indicated placing variables that has the same number in front of it and 0 for the opposite situation.This matrix would be like

```
dimnames    
    a   c   b   d   y   q   i   j   r
a   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
c   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
b   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
d   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
y   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
q   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
i   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
j   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
r   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Anybody know how can I do that?

Comment: Each rownames of a the first matrix that has same number in front would get 1 in second above matrix . For example "b" , "y" have number 2 in front of them so I will put 1 in the second matrix in arrays of "b" and "y". And put 0 for arrays of "a" and "b" bcz they don't have same values in front of them @ZheyuanLi

Comment: your right it was a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dist`:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "rownames    V1
                 a   1
                 c   3
                 b   2
                 d   4
                 y   2
                 q   4
                 i   1
                 j   1
                 r   3", header = TRUE)

res <- as.matrix(dist(DF$V1)) == 0L
#alternatively:
#res <- !as.matrix(dist(DF$V1)) 
#diag(res) <- 0L #for the first version of the question, i.e. a zero diagonal
res <- +(res) #for the second version, i.e. to coerce to an integer matrix
dimnames(res) <- list(DF$rownames, DF$rownames)
#  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
#2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
#3 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
#4 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
#5 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
#6 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
#7 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
#8 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
#9 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi that is an awesome solution to the problem! I suggest you to make a reply since this will be valuable for many!

Comment: Thank you @Roland I think if I put the diameter of the res matrix 1 it would be the correct answer. Really thank you.

Comment: @minoo I don't under understand your comment. I've reproduced your expected output. What is "the diameter" of a matrix? Edit: Never mind. See my edit.

Comment: I would be really grateful if you put your answer as a reply to make me understand it better. @z

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Sure. I'd need to benchmark for the more efficient version. Probably depends on the size. For big input I'd return a sparse matrix anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `table` and `crossprod`.

```
tcrossprod(table(DF))     
#         rownames
# rownames a b c d i j q r y
#        a 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
#        b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
#        c 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
#        d 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
#        i 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
#        j 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
#        q 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
#        r 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
#        y 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

If you want the row and column order as they are found in the data, rather than alphanumerically, you can subset

```
tcrossprod(table(DF))[DF$rownames, DF$rownames]
```

or use factor

```
tcrossprod(table(factor(DF$rownames, levels=unique(DF$rownames)), DF$V1))
```

If your data is large or sparse, you can use the sparse matrix algebra in `xtabs`, with similar ways to change the order of the resulting table as before.

```
Matrix::tcrossprod(xtabs(data=DF, ~ rownames + V1, sparse=TRUE))
```