# Convert a 2 column dataframe into a symmetric binary matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to make a symmetric matrix in R where if column A=dataSet1 and column B=dataSet2 appear together in the same row, then set in the matrix to 1 else it is 0.  However, I can not seem to understand the tcrossprod() function in R.  I have been able use table to make a unsymmetrical matrix but no luck with the (symmetric/square) matrix.

I tried follow this example but no success:
[Building a symmetric binary matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214014/building-a-symmetric-binary-matrix)

My data:

```
   structure(list(dataSet1 = c("g14773.t1", "g6302.t1", "g399.t1", 
"g15590.t1", "g2595.t1", "g149.t1"), dataSet2 = c("g6302.t1", 
"g14773.t1", "g482.t1", "g14053.t1", "g1006.t1", "g6302.t1")), .Names = c("dataSet1", 
"dataSet2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Whenever I use the tcrossprod function I get incorrect binary present and values are missing:

```
 tcrossprod(table(head(Data)))
              dataSet2
  dataSet1    g14773.t1 g149.t1 g15590.t1 g2595.t1 g399.t1 g6302.t1
  g14773.t1         1       1         0        0       0        0
  g149.t1           1       1         0        0       0        0
  g15590.t1         0       0         1        0       0        0
  g2595.t1          0       0         0        1       0        0
  g399.t1           0       0         0        0       1        0
  g6302.t1          0       0         0        0       0        1
```

Any recommendations for how to make it into a symmetric matrix like below:

```
structure(list(g14773.t1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), g6302.t1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g399.t1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g15590.t1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g2595.t1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), g149.t1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g482.t1 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g14053.t1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), g1006.t1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L)), .Names = c("g14773.t1", "g6302.t1", "g399.t1", "g15590.t1", 
"g2595.t1", "g149.t1", "g482.t1", "g14053.t1", "g1006.t1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("g14773.t1", 
"g6302.t1", "g399.t1", "g15590.t1", "g2595.t1", "g149.t1", "g482.t1", 
"g14053.t1", "g1006.t1"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your columns `df$dataSet1` and `df$dataSet2` to `factor`, specifying that their levels are the union of values found in both columns. And then simply use `table`:

```
df$dataSet1 = factor(df$dataSet1,levels=union(df$dataSet1,df$dataSet2))
df$dataSet2 = factor(df$dataSet2,levels=union(df$dataSet1,df$dataSet2))
res = table(df)
```

`Table` will include a count rather than a 0/1 value, so for example if two values are found twice together, the value in the matrix will be 2.
If that's an issue, you can add:

```
res[res>0] = 1
```

Result:

```
           dataSet2
dataSet1    g14773.t1 g6302.t1 g399.t1 g15590.t1 g2595.t1 g149.t1 g482.t1 g14053.t1 g1006.t1
  g14773.t1         0        1       0         0        0       0       0         0        0
  g6302.t1          1        0       0         0        0       0       0         0        0
  g399.t1           0        0       0         0        0       0       1         0        0
  g15590.t1         0        0       0         0        0       0       0         1        0
  g2595.t1          0        0       0         0        0       0       0         0        1
  g149.t1           0        1       0         0        0       0       0         0        0
  g482.t1           0        0       0         0        0       0       0         0        0
  g14053.t1         0        0       0         0        0       0       0         0        0
  g1006.t1          0        0       0         0        0       0       0         0        0
```

Comment: thanks for the help and I didn't even think about doing the union at all.

Comment: Yep defining the levels of the factor does the trick here. By default, `table` will keep all the levels even if unused.